# Not Receiving html rendering of API call

Tags: javascript, api, async-await

I am trying to practice making request to 3rd party api's and I am not able to render the response to html, but I when I console log it, and I get a response strangely. Refer to code below.

**script.js**

```
async function getCountries(){
  let url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/lang/es'
  try{
    let res = await fetch(url);
    return await res.json()
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
}

async function renderCountries(){
  let countries = getCountries();
  console.log(countries)
  let html = '';
  countries.forEach(country =>{
    let htmlSeg = `
    <div class="user">
      <h2>${country.name}</h2>
      <p>${country.capital}</p>
      <p>${country.region}</p>
      <p>${country.subregion}</p>
    </div>`;

    html += htmlSeg;

    
})

let container = document.querySelector('#spot')
container.innerHTML = html

}

renderCountries()
```

**index.html**

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hi</h1>
    <div class ='spot'>

    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error I get is this:

```
script.js:15 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: countries.forEach is not a function
    at renderCountries (script.js:15)
    at script.js:34
```

Here is an example of the response I get when console logging.

```
0: {name: "Argentina", topLevelDomain: Array(1), alpha2Code: "AR", alpha3Code: "ARG", callingCodes: Array(1), …}
1: {name: "Belize", topLevelDomain: Array(1), alpha2Code: "BZ", alpha3Code: "BLZ", callingCodes: Array(1), …}
2: {name: "Bolivia (Plurinational State of)", topLevelDomain: Array(1), alpha2Code: "BO", alpha3Code: "BOL", callingCodes: Array(1), …}
3: {name: "Chile", topLevelDomain: Array(1), alpha2Code: "CL", alpha3Code: "CHL", calli
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `await`

```
let countries = await getCountries();
```